# unable to scroll to the label for input field with an error message

Tags: jquery, scroll

I earlier asked another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885558/jquery-scroll-to-specific-div-position-in-case-of-error-and-focus/8885882#comment11111652_8885882)
However, I later realized that my requirements are a little different. The above referenced solution takes me only to the error div but I need to scroll up slightly above that to the label for the input text field. Below is the html.

```
<label class="label_required" for="phone_num_key"></label>
 <table class="table_Box">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="someId" class="redAlert">

       <Some more mark up here>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

How can I scroll up to the label instead of the tr element with class 'redAlert'
I tried the below but it didn't work for me.

```
var errorDiv= $('.redAlert:visible').first();
var errorLabel = errorDiv.parent("table").prev("label");
// also tried this
//var errorLabel = errorDiv.closest("label").prev();
var scrollPosition = (errorLabel.offset().top); 
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollPosition);
```

Looks like the .offeset() function cannot be called on Labels ?

Edit - Please note that there are multiple such labels on the form so I cannot basically use the class selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`offset()` does work. problem is `parent()`. 
use `errorDiv.parents('table').prev('label');`

FYI,

> **.parent( [selector] )**
>
> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .parent() method allows us to search through the parents of these
>   elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the
>   matching elements. *The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar,
>   except that the latter only travels **a single** level up the DOM tree.*
>
> ```
>                                            from http://api.jquery.com/parent/
> ```

Comment: @user1006072 glad to hear that, just don't forget to check this answer :)

Comment: Another quick question - how would I focus on the immediate next input element after the error div ?

Comment: @user1006072 Is the input element sibling of error div? if it is immediately following object, you can use next(). check it: http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: There is a bunch of other mark up after the error div such as                      <tr><td><div><table>...... <input>.. . I was looking for something like  - find the next input element (no matter the mark up in between) . Is there such jquery selector ?

Comment: @user1006072 If it is not necessary, you'd better use proper jquery selector. don't navigate via DOM tree. but if you have to, you can use `nextAll('input').first()` note that it works that input is on the same level with the error div in DOM tree. otherwise you have to use parent/parents/find to make it same. I can help you more precisely if you give me your code.

Comment: Thanks Much Sang. I figured it out. Your tips/explanation above was very good and helpful.