# Scroll to Validation Summary - ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When a user clicks a button in my application that causes validation errors, is there a way to have the page scroll to the location of the Validation Summary if there are errors? I need to do this for both cases:

1. Client Validation prevents the page from submitting
2. Server Validation redisplays the web page

Is there an easy way to accomplish this in MVC?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/798949/290343)?

Comment: @OferZelig Considering that question is talking about WebForms and not MVC...no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jquery scroll to specific div position in case of error and focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885558/jquery-scroll-to-specific-div-position-in-case-of-error-and-focus) 
<-- This post has a similar requirement - the stated solution is a js function firing on dom-load that scrolls the window to the desired position.  Correctly implemented, this could create a solution for both client & server side validation.